# JQuery populated labels are not showing up on Render

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I'm populating labels in a modpopup using jquery...

```js
function OpenForm(dirnm, pub, cldate) {
  
            $(".lblDirectory").html(dirnm);
            $(".lblPublisher").html(pub);
            $(".lblDueDate").html(cldate);
  
  }
```

```html
<b>Directory:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="lblDirectory"></label><br />
<b>Publisher:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="lblPublisher"></label><br />
<b>Due Date:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="lblDueDate"></label><br />
```

But on the code behind Render those labels are not populated even when it shows that it is populated on screen.

```js
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    If Not (Page Is Nothing) Then
        Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Me)
    End If
    If SaveFile = True Then
        Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
        Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        MyBase.RenderChildren(htw)
        Dim html As String
        html = sb.ToString
        SignWebApproval(html)
    End If
    MyBase.Render(writer)

    ....

End Sub
```

Is there something I'm missing?